# Why output is one address when I want to grab some addresses

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to grab the specific positional addresses in every layer .I start at this address:

```
https://pr4e.dr-chuck.com/tsugi/mod/python-data/data/known_by_Teigon.html
```

the first loop I want to parse every layer HTML:

```
for i in range(0,18+1):
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
tags = soup('a')
```

the second loop I want to grab the special positional addresses:

```
for tag in tags:
    b=0
    b+=1
    while b==7:
        url=tag.get('href',None)
        print url
        break
```

But the output is one address,not 18 addresses.

Comment: show code in one piece - when do you call second loop ? inside first ?

Answer (score 0):

```
b=0
b+=1
while b==7:
  # rest
```

in this code `b` is always `1` so you never run code inside `while`.

By the way if `b` will be `7` then you will run code inside `while` but it will never stop because you don't change `b` inside `while` and `b == 7` will be always True.

-

Maybe you need `for b in range(7):`